# Can I use local compute for Azure AutoML Forecasting?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I would like to use my PC to train a model using Azure AutoML Forecasting, rather than paying for a compute cluster.

I am using the Azure ML Python SDK v2, and when setting the compute to `local`, I get an error `NoneType' object does not support item assignment`

```py
forecasting_job = automl.forecasting(
    compute = "local",
    ...
)

returned_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(forecasting_job)
```

If I set the compute to a cluster in Azure ML workspace, I get no error, and the job is submitted.

Is using a local PC for training possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can train model locally using custom training script and setting up the environment configuration.
Follow below steps,
First, import required libraries.

```
from  azureml.core.workspace  import  Workspace
from  azureml.core  import  Experiment
from  azureml.core  import  Environment
from  azureml.core  import  ScriptRunConfig
```

initialize your workspace object.

```
ws = Workspace(workspace_name="yourWorkspace",resource_group="yourResourcegroup",subscription_id="your subscription id")
print(ws.name, ws.resource_group, ws.location, ws.subscription_id, sep='\n')
```

Create an experiment.

```
exp = Experiment(workspace=ws, name='trainl')
```

Know create user managed environment.

```
userEnv = Environment("env")
userEnv.python.user_managed_dependencies = True
```

You can also choose your interpreter as below

```
userEnv.python.interpreter_path = '/home/xxxx/envs/myenv/bin/python'
```

Then submit your forecast script along with the folder having dependencies and above created environment as below.

```
src = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='./scripts', script='train.py', environment=userEnv)
```

Here, `train.py` is the main script and the depending datasets and scripts can be in `scripts` folder.

In my case it is only `mylib.py` as shown below.

[image]

Code in `train.py` is on **ridge** regression model, you can customize to your forecasting.
Here is the sample code,

```
from  sklearn.datasets  import  load_diabetes
from  sklearn.linear_model  import  Ridge
from  sklearn.metrics  import  mean_squared_error
from  sklearn.model_selection  import  train_test_split
from  azureml.core.run  import  Run
import  os
import  mylib
import  joblib

os.makedirs('./outputs', exist_ok=True)
X, y = load_diabetes(return_X_y=True)
run = Run.get_context()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
alphas = mylib.get_alphas()

for  alpha  in  alphas:
    reg = Ridge(alpha=alpha)
    reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    preds = reg.predict(X_test)
    mse = mean_squared_error(preds, y_test)
    
    run.log('alpha', alpha)
    run.log('mse', mse)
   
    model_file_name = 'ridge_{0:.2f}.pkl'.format(alpha)
    
    with  open(model_file_name, "wb") as  file:
        joblib.dump(value=reg, filename=os.path.join('./outputs/',model_file_name))
        print('alpha is {0:.2f}, and mse is {1:0.2f}'.format(alpha, mse))
```

You can see `run.log()` command ,which is used to log  the computation result.

Now, submit the experiment.

```
run = exp.submit(src)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output = True)
```

And below is the result.

```
Execution Summary ================= 
RunId:trainl_1682316457_53f4f8d3
{'runId': 'trainl_1682316457_53f4f8d3',
 'target': 'local', 
 'status': 'Completed', 
 'startTimeUtc': '2023-04-24T06:10:59.353841Z', 
 'endTimeUtc': '2023-04-24T06:16:56.892061Z',
 'services': {}, 
 'properties': {'_azureml.ComputeTargetType': 'local', 
 'ContentSnapshotId': '0a26ea0d-0e81-43a4-8c67-64282d09d72d'}, 
 'inputDatasets': [], 
 'outputDatasets': [], 
 'runDefinition': {'script': 'train.py', 
 'command': '', 
 'useAbsolutePath': False, 
 'arguments': [], 
 'sourceDirectoryDataStore': None, 
 'framework': 'Python', 
 'communicator': 'None', 
 'target': 'local', 
 'dataReferences': {}, 
 'data': {}, 
 'outputData': {}, 
 'datacaches': [], 
 'jobName': None, 
 'maxRunDurationSeconds': 2592000, 'nodeCount': 1,
 ...
 'parameters': []},
```

You can try this with your custom training script.
Refer below documentation for more information.
[Local-train](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/training/train-on-local/train-on-local.ipynb)

Comment: This doesn't look like AutoML?

Comment: Yes. This is one way to train locally. Using AutoML you need to specify the `compute-target` which i tried as per your question, adding `local`. Even i got the same error.
As per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/migrate-to-v2-execution-automl?view=azureml-api-2) the `compute-target` need to provide for both SDK v1 and v2. So in AutoML it may not possible to submit job giving as `local`. For more information on local runs refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/migrate-to-v2-local-runs?view=azureml-api-2)